# Hibernate add Restriction ( equals ) only if the parameter is not null

Tags: java, hibernate

how do i check if  the parameter is null?
Depending on the result i want to add or not to add the Restriction

if person.getLastName() == null i don't want to add the relevant restriction, 
how do i do this?

```
    persons = session.createCriteria(PersonEntity.class).add(
                Restrictions.eq("LastName", person.getLastName())).add(
                Restrictions.eq("FirstName", person.getFirstName())).add(
                Restrictions.eq("email", person.getUser().getEmail()))
                .list();
```

Thanks, tania

Answer (score 12):

You could just do it with a normal if in a method:

```
private void addRestrictionIfNotNull(Criteria criteria, String propertyName, Object value) {
    if (value != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(propertyName, value));
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PersonEntity.class);
addRestrictionIfNotNull(critera, "LastName", person.getLastName());
addRestrictionIfNotNull(critera, "FirstName", person.getFirstName());
addRestrictionIfNotNull(critera, "email", person.getEmail());

persons = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use such complex restriction:

```
Restrictions.or(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNotNull("propName"), Restrictions.eq("propName", propValue)), Restrictions.isNull("propName"));
```

If I understand you correct it will do what you expect.

Result of the inner restriction *Restrictions.eq("propName", propValue)* will affect the result of the query only if specified property is not null.

PS. I know that it seems too obfuscated but for now I can't imagine another way to do this.

Comment: The question is for checking nullity for the given value that is to be matched, but not the field value. Your solution seems good but it will check for nullity for the "propName" field in database while here (as per the question), "propValue" is to be checked for nullity.

Comment: The question is talking about the object compare to and not the db field ```@param value The value to use in comparison```

Answer (score 0):

So, u can do like this,

```
session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(PersonEntity.class).add(
                Restrictions.eq("FirstName", person.getFirstName())).add(
                Restrictions.eq("email", person.getUser().getEmail()));
if(person.getLastName()!=null){
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("LastName", person.getLastName()));
}
person=(PersonVO)crit.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `last_name` column is always **not null** in the table, you can try something like below :

```
String lastName = .. ;

.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(lastName != null ? "this_.last_name = "+ lastName : "this_.last_name is not null "))
```

Here the `last_name` will be your table column name.